# How run pre-trained darknet yolov4 model using python script?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, darknet, yolov4

I am developing a napari plugin in Python language. This plugin makes a object detection using darknet Yolov4. Before making a napari plugin, I started to write a notebook which making inference. My environment is windows 10.

I followed instruction in this [website](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet). But, my problem is focused on this command :

```
Folder_darknet='C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/darknet/'

os.chdir(Folder_darknet)

!chmod +x ./darknet

!./darknet detector test "C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/obj.data" "C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/yolov4-tiny-test.cfg" "C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/backup/yolov4-tiny-train_best.weights" -thresh 0.20 -dont_show -out "C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/Prediction.csv" < "C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/test.txt"
```

I used **subprocess** python library to run windows command line but I can't handle it :

> No command is recognized as an internal or external command

Here the code :

```
Folder_darknet='C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/darknet/'

os.chdir(Folder_darknet)

subprocess.run([".\darknet","detector","test","C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/obj.data","C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/yolov4-tiny-test.cfg","C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/backup/yolov4-tiny-train_best.weights","-thresh","0.20","-dont_show","-out","C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/Prediction.csv","<","C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Université de Bourgogne/Documents/Stage/yolo/main_folder/Model_ALL_views/test.txt"],shell=True)
```

You can find the full code in my [notebook](https://github.com/hereariim/apple-propo/blob/main/apple-propo.ipynb)

Is it a good idea to use **subprocess** to execute the darknet command ?

Kindly help me, I will be highly grateful to all of you.
Thanks you for your support.
Best,

Comment: you say you used `subprocess`, but don't show your code! to help us help you, include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @ti7, here, i completed my questions and i added my code + github link to find the full code. thank you

Comment: does this work if you pass `darknet.exe`? the error from `subprocess` is simply that it can't find `.\darknet` (which is probably an impossible name and should at least be `./darknet` under Linux) .. additionally, the instructions without the extension are for Linux (such as `chmod +x _`)! lightly reading the README, you may need to specify the destination path for the build and/or manually find the output executable (`darknet.exe`) after building .. finally, you may find that using OneDrive creates problems for you (though I suspect that would be a secondary issue to the mis-naming!)

Comment: Why not use opencv for inference? https://lindevs.com/yolov4-object-detection-using-opencv/